# How to retrieve files from a Sharepoint Folder with metadata(column) to check wether the file exists or not?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-online, last-modified

I am looking to upload the file to SharePoint using Add-PnPFile, but it overwrites the file every time.
I want to check if the file exists or not ? If yes then if it is modified in the last day or not ?
If yes then i will upload the file(overwrite the existing file using add-pnpfile) else I skip the file and check for the next file ?

Is there anyway ?

```html
#install and import module
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 

#Get Connection to the url
Connect-PnPOnline "Some SharePoint Url" -UseWebLogin

#get the files from a local folder
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Some Local FolderPath" -Recurse

#Now check wether the file is being modified or not ? 
foreach($File in $Files){
    
#Logic to check if the file exists in the sharepoint folder or not ? If it exist then i want to check wether it is being modified or not ? if yes then i will add the file
#if not then i will skip that file and check for other files.
        
        #Calculating LastWritetime for the file.
        $LastWriteTimeForThisFile = $File.LastWriteTime.Day
        $difference = (Get-Date).Day - $LastWriteTimeForThisFile
    
        if(file exists ? then check the difference in Lastmodified dates)
        if ( $difference -lt 1) 
        {
         
         $upload = Add-PnPFile -Path $File.FullName -Folder $SharePointFolderPath
         $message = "Successfully Uploaded"  #this i will be having an entry in log file.
        }
        else{
         $message = Not Modified so not uploading again #this i will be having an entry in log file.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following, it should work for you.

```
foreach($File in $Files){
    #Calculating LastWritetime for the file.
    $LastWriteTimeForThisFile = $File.LastWriteTime
    $difference = (Get-Date) - $LastWriteTimeForThisFile
    
    #Check if File exists Already
    $fileURL= $SharePointFolderPath+"/"+$file.name

    $FileExists = Get-PnPFile -Url $fileURL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
    if($FileExists){
        if ( $difference.days -lt 1) {         
         $upload = Add-PnPFile -Path $File.FullName -Folder $SharePointFolderPath
         $message = "Successfully Uploaded"  #this i will be having an entry in log file.
        }
        else{
         $message = Not Modified so not uploading again #this i will be having an entry in log file.
        }
    }
    #If File doesnot exist, upload the file.
    Else{
        $upload = Add-PnPFile -Path $File.FullName -Folder $SharePointFolderPath
        $message = "Successfully Uploaded"  #this i will be having an entry in log file.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) it did exactly what it should